# Applying for UK visitor visa from Germany as an international student

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm applying for a friend's visitor visa from Germany. Is it okay if she has have 4 months left on her student visa while applying for uk tourist visa? It has not been stated explicitly if they need a minimum amount of months on the residence permit to my knowledge.

Comment: For completeness, what is your friend’s citizenship? And how much time will remain on her student visa *at the end of* the proposed UK visit? AFAIK there is no required minimum, however bear in mind that UK visitor visas are (almost always) valid for 6 months. You might want to avoid a situation where the student visa expires *before* the UK visa (if granted). Providing proof of ties to country of citizenship/permanent residence might be an idea

Comment: My friend's Indian. Unfortunately that is the situation. Her visa will expire 2 months prior to the 6 month mark. The consulate told me that residency should not be an issue for short term visas granted that they can prove their residency at the time of application. Apart from providing proof of enrollment in Uni, what else could I possibly provide?